# Segmentation Fault in Vertical Redundancy Check

Tags: c, pointers, error-detection

I am trying to make program in C for vertical redundancy check. The Code is given below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

    int main()
    {
        int fd,i;
        char *data = "01010101010111110101010101011111";
        int count = 0,bit_count=0;
        char *parity_bit_array = NULL;
        char *data_to_send = NULL;
        char *stream_name = "Named Stream";
        do
        {
            if(*data == '1' && bit_count <= 8)
            {
                count++;
                if(bit_count == 8) 
                {
                        if( count % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            *parity_bit_array = '1';
                            count = 0;
                            bit_count = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *parity_bit_array = '0';
                            count = 0;
                            bit_count = 0;
                        }
                }
            }
            bit_count++;
            data++;
        } while( !data);
        do
        {
            if(bit_count <= 8)
            {
                *data_to_send++ = *parity_bit_array++;
            }
            *data_to_send++ =  *data;
        } while( !data );
        printf("%s \n",data_to_send);
        mkfifo(stream_name,0666);
        fd = open(stream_name,O_WRONLY);
        write(fd,data_to_send,sizeof(data_to_send));
        close(fd);
        unlink(stream_name);
        return 0;
    }
```

The file shown below is the sender file of which data is to be read by the receiver.
By using sized array it is working properly but i like to use it with Pointer.
**Main Variables in this code :**

1. **data** : Data on which VRC to be implemented
2. **count** : Counting 1 for Even Parity Bit
3. **bit_count** : Counting 8 Bits
4. **parity_bit_array** : To Collect Parity Bit for Every Single Byte present in data
5. **data_to_send** : Combination made by data + parity_bit_array

Ex: 
**data :** 01110000
**parity_bit_array :** 1
**data_to_send :** 01110000**1**

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question ?

Comment: @PaulR i think you forgot to read the title...it is saying that there is a Segmentation Fault occurring in this code

Comment: Stating that you have a segmentation fault is not a question. Note that if you want to know *why* you're getting a seg fault then you might consider helping your readers by indicating which line the seg fault occurs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for your char pointers and you are trying to write to them which will lead to undefined behavior hence segmentation fault.

```
 *parity_bit_array = '1';
```

There are multiple such cases in this code.

```
 char *data_to_send = NULL;
```

data_to_send pointer is never allocated memory and you try to write to it

```
*data_to_send++ = *parity_bit_array++;
```

Allocate memory to char pointers like

```
 char *data_to_send = malloc(20);
```

While writing to this array if you see 20 bytes is already written just do realloc() for the same memory

```
char *temp = realloc(data_to_send,40);
if(temp != NULL)
data_to_send = temp;
```

Comment: how to allocate memory to char pointers until we don't know how much characters are to be stored in it

Comment: @HarshKanakhara Allocate some random memory if you don't know. or Use realloc() to keep incrementing memory instead of allocating random memory. `BUT ALLOCATE MEMORY`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For me right now to use realloc() on pointers is a bit hard so i have allocated random memory to uninitialized pointers and done some modification. Now it is working fine...!!!

Comment: @HarshKanakhara Cool !! Make things work first later rest of the things needs to be handled :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

1. `} while( !data);`  is wrong, you should use : `} while( *data != 0);`

   This can indirectly cause segmentation fault(If you are lucky) making the   code loop indefinably.
2. Memory is not allocated to  `*parity_bit_array` and `*data_to_send`.
   Accessing un-allocated memory is undefined behavior and can cause anything including segmentation fault.
3. `write(fd,data_to_send,sizeof(data_to_send));` should be `write(fd,data_to_send,sizeof(*data_to_send));` Or something like that as per your logic.

Comment: i have corrected the first problem of do-while statement but i don't know how to initialize a char pointer until i don't know how much characters are to be stored in it. Also about the 3rd problem according to the c syntax for write function it should be sizeof() only

Comment: @HarshKanakhara I have modified 3rd problem.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara for second problem you can consider maximum possible string size and allocate memory accordingly using `malloc` ,OR consider  `realloc`